# How to combine Google Authentication and API key Authentication using Blazor?

Tags: authentication, google-authentication, blazor-server-side, .net-core-3.1

I have a Blazor application using .NET Core 3.1.
I use Google authentication to log in as explained in this article, written by @MichaelWashington https://blazorhelpwebsite.com/ViewBlogPost/19
I add `[Authorize]` to my Controller and only logged in user can access my controller.

I also need to give access to my controller using an API key. I followed this article, written by @JosefOttosson: https://josef.codes/asp-net-core-protect-your-api-with-api-keys/ this is working fine as well when I replace `[Authorize]` with `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationConstants.ApiKeyDefaultScheme)]`

But now I don't have access to my controller via my Blazer site. So I added `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationConstants.GoogleAuthenticationScheme)]` but now I get CORS errors:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=[...] 
(redirected from 'https://localhost:44380/api/client/2/upload/foo') 
from origin 'https://localhost:44380' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I've tried numerous options but I still keep getting this error. Replacing the two `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes ...` with `[Authorize]` makes my front-end work again but my Postman call (mimicking a 3rd party call) fails.

How can I combine these two authentication methods?

In `public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)` I have

```cs
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

In `public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` I have at the top:

```cs
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins, builder => builder
         .WithOrigins("http://localhost:44380/")
         .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true)
         .AllowAnyMethod()
         .AllowAnyHeader());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured it out. I was banging my head because sometimes it did work and sometimes it didn't. When I logged out and then in again on the frontend using Google Authentication it never worked.
In the Login code

```cs
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
         CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
         new ClaimsPrincipal(GoogleUser),
         authProperties);
```

is used. Watch the `CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme`. It is using/setting a different scheme.

So after adding `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]` my controller works all the time.

My controller now looks like this:

```cs
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationConstants.GoogleAuthenticationScheme)]
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationConstants.ApiKeyDefaultScheme)]
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
    public class MetaController : BaseApiController
```

I hope it helps somebody else. It took me two days ;-)